# What's the nature of the clause following "It's time"?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

This must have come up before, but somehow I couldn't find any relevant post. Nor could I find any reference.

> (1) *It's time [you went to bed].*
>
> (2) *It's time [(for you) to go to bed].*

What's the nature of the [clause] here?
I don't think it's a relative clause modifying *time*.
Nor do I think it's an extraposed subject.
Is it some kind of a complement clause of the expression *It's time*?

Comment: (1) is short for _time (that) you went to bed_, a tensed (past tense) complement clause with optional complementizer _that_, and (2) is an untensed infinitive complement clause with optional subject complementizer _for you_. It turns out that _be time_ can take either type, but not gerund complements (*_It's time your going to bed_) or _wh_-clauses.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks. So you think it's a complement clause of the entire expression _It's time_? Do you happen to know of any reference on the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. See McCawley 1998, chapter 3 on Complements.

Comment: (1) is a declarative content clause (the subordinator "that" can optionally be added), functioning as complement of "time". (2) is a _to_-infinitival clause functioning as complement of "time". It contains a subject, "you", and thus contains the clause subordinator "for" appearing at the beginning of the clause right before the subject. "To" is also a subordinator introducing the predicate VP "to go to bed".

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you mean "The Syntactic Phenomena of English"? It's chapter 5 that's on 'complements', and it doesn't seem to discuss 'it's time'. Are you sure that it discusses the construction?

Comment: @JK2 Sorry about the chapter number. Of course it doesn't list all the predicates that have complements. What exactly do you mean by "the construction"? Are you only interested in the lexical item _time_? I can give you a list of all the example sentences in the OED with the word _time_ in them, if that's useful; there are probly more than 10,000, since it's a common word.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm asking specifically about the construction "It's time", not just the word "time". So the reference should discuss the construction, and the nature of the [clause]. As far as I know McCawley 1998 doesn't discuss the construction at all.

Comment: @JK2 The title of your question asks about the clause **following** "it's time. Now you're asking about "it's time". What exactly is it that you're asking about?

Comment: @BillJ I may have stated simply "the construction _It's time_, not just the word _time_", but I think you know I meant "the nature of the [clause] following the construction _It's time_, not just the nature of the [clause] following the word _time_," which is an unnecessarily complex thing to say.

Comment: Is this a case of it-extraposition? It sounds that way, but "[That you went to bed] is time" doesn't really make sense either.

Comment: So the question is what kind of clause the idiomatic predicate _be time (for) s.t,_ with the sense of 'do s.t. now', governs -- infinitives and _that_ clauses work, but gerunds require _for_, as do other nouns (_It's time for Beany!_), and I can't get any _wh_-clauses to work. As I said, these look and work like complement clauses; if that's forbidden by the nomenklatura, call them something else.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give an answer that assumes an understanding of [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), a.k.a. *CGEL*, since the OP has asked questions about it before, and explaining this background knowledge would make my answer even longer than it already is.

> (1) It's time [you went to bed].

According to CGEL, in this case "you went to bed" is a subordinate content clause licensed, not by a verb, but by a verbal idiom. It's not a complement of the noun *time* because, while "It is time you were in bed" is valid, *"The time you were in bed has arrived" is not (p. 1021). CGEL isn't totally clear on this point, but I think H&P take the clause to be a complement of *is,* albeit a complement that cannot strictly speaking be classified as direct or indirect, since it's licensed, neither by the head *is* nor by the dependent *time,* but by the idiom consisting of both. (They mention this construction again on p. 1004, but they don't discuss the syntax there.)

> (2) It's time [(for you) to go to bed].

This is more complicated, and it's not a construction that CGEL addresses directly.

*Time* can occur on its own as a noncount noun with an infinitival clause, as in "Time to rest is a luxury these days" or "There won't be time to read during the trip." In this case, you can put an *in which* before the *to* (provided there's no subject like "for you"), as in "You won't have any time in which to read," so it seems we must treat this as an infinitival relative clause. Likewise in "The time to leave has now arrived," though there we need an *at which* instead of an *in which* and the meaning concerns deontic necessity rather than dynamic possibility.

But I don't think that that's the usage of *time* found in (2). There, even if we remove the "for you," we can't add an "in/at which"; *"It's time in/at which to go to bed" is pretty clearly invalid. We also can't add a determiner to (2); *"It's the time for you to go to bed" is likewise invalid. Moreover, I'm pretty sure that the modifier *high* can be added to *time* in this idiom, but not elsewhere: "It's high time for you to leave" is valid, but *"The high time for you to leave has arrived" is not, even though both are valid without the "high."

(Edit: one could argue that, though the versions with *in/at which* are relative infinitives, the versions without those are infinitival complements of the noun *time,* but I still don't think that this use of *time* would adequately explain sentences like (2) for the other reasons I've mentioned.)

Instead, I think we need to take "(for you) to go to bed" again as a complement licensed by the "it's time" idiom. This gives the idiom three patterns of complementation:

1. With no internal complement: "It's time."
2. With a *to*-infinitival complement: "It's time (for you) to leave."
3. With a content clause complement: "It's time (that) you left."

Note that the words "high" and "about" can modify "time" in all of (1)-(3), as in "It's high time" or "It's about time," whereas I think these modifiers generally can't be used with *time* in the same sense outside of this specific idiom.

Comment: +1 for finding the discussion in CGEL (p. 1021). Somehow CGEL's lexical index for _time_ doesn't list that page. I'd probably award the bounty as soon as I can. Thank you!